# Model method error while trying to navigate

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have several Backbone Models rendered  in a Collection View, and also I have a route that should render a view of that model. So, here come the views

`resume.js`

```
// this renders a single model for a collection view
var ResumeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    model: new Resume(),
    initialize: function () {
        this.template = _.template($('#resume').html());
    },
    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON));
        return this;
    }
});
```

`#resume template`

```
<section id="resume">
    <h1><%= profession %></h1>
    <!-- !!!!! The link for a router which should navigate to ShowResume view -->
    <a href="#resumes/<%= id %>">View Details</a>
</section>
```

Collection view:

```
var ResumeList = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function (options) {
        this.collection = options.collection;
        this.collection.on('add', this.render, this);
        // Getting the data from JSON-server
        this.collection.fetch({
            success: function (res) {
                _.each(res.toJSON(), function (item) {
                    console.log("GET a model with " + item.id);
                });
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log("Failed to GET"); 
            }
        });
    },
    render: function () {
        var self = this;
        this.$el.html('');
        _.each(this.collection.toArray(), function (cv) {
            self.$el.append((new ResumeView({model: cv})).render().$el);
        });
        return this;
    }        
});
```

The code above works perfectly and does exactly what I need -- an array of models is fetched from my local JSON-server and each model is displayed within a collection view. However, the trouble starts when I try to navigate through my link in the template above. Here comes the router:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '': home,
        'resumes/:id': 'showResume'
    },
    initialize: function (options) {
        // layout is set in main.js
        this.layout = options.layout
    },
    home: function () {
        this.layout.render(new ResumeList({collection: resumes}));
    },
    showResume: function (cv) {
        this.layout.render(new ShowResume({model: cv}));
    }
});
```

and finally the `ShowResume` view:

```
var ShowResume = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function (options) {
        this.model = options.model;
        this.template = _.template($('#full-resume').html());
    },
    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    }
});
```

I didn't provide the template for this view because it is quite large, but the error is following: whenever I try to navigate to a link, a view tries to render, but returns me the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: this.model.toJSON is not a function.` I suspect that my `showResume` method in router is invalid, but I can't actually get how to make it work in right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the string `id` of the url `'resumes/:id'` as the model of the view.

This should solve it.

```
showResume: function (id) {
   this.layout.render(new ShowResume({
       model: new Backbone.Model({ 
           id: id,
           profession: "teacher" // you can pass data like this 
       })
   }));
}
```

But you should fetch the data in the controller and react accordingly in the view.

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '*otherwise': 'home', // notice the catch all
        'resumes/:id': 'showResume'
    },
    initialize: function(options) {
        // layout is set in main.js
        this.layout = options.layout
    },
    home: function() {
        this.layout.render(new ResumeList({ collection: resumes }));
    },
    showResume: function(id) {
        // lazily create the view and keep it
        if (!this.showResume) {
            this.showResume = new ShowResume({ model: new Backbone.Model() });
        }

        // use the view's model and fetch
        this.showResume.model.set('id', id).fetch({
            context: this,
            success: function(){
                this.layout.render(this.showResume);
            }
        })

    }
});
```

---

Also, `this.model = options.model;` is unnecessary as [Backbone automatically picks up](http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor) `model`, `collection`, `el`, `id`, `className`, `tagName`, `attributes` and `events`, extending the view with them.

Comment: Thank you again Emile! strange, but now it returns me an error `profession is not defined`, though the template is almost the same as the provided above

Comment: @AlexNikolaev94 I've updated the answer to provide a way it could work, but that's really basic and you would rather check for example online which demonstrate good patterns for routing and views.

Comment: thank you, Emile! it worked, but now it returns the same error as the one I mentioned in my previous question: `A "url" property or function must be specified`. I should figure out how to fetch data received from collection

Comment: @AlexNikolaev94 Ask a question with the collection, model and the view and where they are used.